# How to load a File using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

In Java I want to load a file [whatever format it is] in its own format using `JFileChooser`.  Means I don't want to read and display the contents inside my `JFrame`. Instead I want them to open/load like an image open in a Windows Photo  Viewer/Irfan Viewer and a PDF open in Adobe Reader By clicking a Button.

I had searched a lot. But all tutorial I  read tells how to print a line "opening this file/You are selected this file" by clicking a `JButton`.  Nobody is actually opening/loading a file on a button click. May be I am not getting correctly what they said because I am new to Java. I hope my problem is clear and please help...

Here is the code that I got from a tutorial page:

```
 public class JFileChooserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Test");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
              System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
            }
          }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Here is what I want to do with Java. here is an example with windows:

A Browse Button Click opens this window
[image]

And when I select the XLS file and click OPEN button, an XLS file will open.  I want to do the exact same with Java. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: what do you want ? do you want to see file content ?

Comment: No i want to load/import the file that i selected by clicking a Button.Like what we open a file in windows File Open explorer.

Comment: could you explain more what do you mean with "load/import" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try using [Desktop.open()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);
```

**EDIT**
You need to update here:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);//<-- here
      }
   }
});
```

Sample code from [site](http://www.journaldev.com/864/how-to-open-a-file-in-java):

Comment: I feel this is the better answer by far.  Once established, it is effectively a 'one liner' to use it.  BTW - try `desktop.open(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));`. It is a good demo. because it should work on *any* machine.

Comment: @Sam, what is the issue? Yes it is supposed to open the specified file with the default editor in users pc, i.e. notepad in case of .txt in windows

Comment: This code will open a text/pdf that we mention inside it. [File file = new File("/Users/pankaj/source.txt");]. But how can i browse and select a file and click "OPEN" -Where i want the file to be open. a text document in a Note Pad & an image in Windows photo viewer etc

Comment: OH!!!Thank you very much.I appreciate your effort.I was searching on this for three days.Simple understandable answer for a newbie.Thank you...

Comment: And may i ask what is the purpose for printing the file name?System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select a file and pass it to the system's default application. Unfortunately, this is highly dependable on your operating system. For Windows you can pass that to the command line like this:

```
        String systemcall = "cmd /C start \"\" \"" + absolutePath + "\"";
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        HomeLogger.instance().info("EXECUTE " + systemcall);
        runTime.exec(systemcall);
```

The String absolute Path must be the exact locatin of the file, e.g. "C:\test.txt". I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks i am going to try this,but for me need to study this first.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.  **But for an answer that is both better *and* more reliable, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27289106/418556).**